# Facebook JSON Decoding Events in PHP

Tags: php, json, facebook, object, decoding

I have:

```
$user = json_decode(file_get_contents(
    'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' .
    $cookie['access_token']), true);


var_dump($user);
```

which works fine and gives profile output.

But:

```
$events = json_decode(file_get_contents(
    'https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?access_token=' .
    $cookie['access_token']), true);


var_dump($events);
```

gives:

```
object(stdClass)#5 (1) { ["data"]=> array(0) { } }
```

I'm not sure if this is an empty object, or if I'm not accessing what's inside 'data' correctly. But, I know there are in fact events associated with my profile. Permissions have been granted, so that's not the problem. Anyone know how to return all event names for my profile?

Comment: That is the correct graph api.  How is $cookie being populated?

Comment: Are you sure that there are events?

Comment: I believe events must also be made public. A private event wouldn't be available for an API call. I think.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get events in PHP you have to follow these steps,

Request a proper Access Token follow this link 
[facebook: permanent Page Access Token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token)

Replace your Access token below texted YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN field

```
    <?php
        $json_string = 'https://graph.facebook.com/5973249561/events/?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN&fields=id,name,description,start_time,place,cover,end_time&limit=999';
        $obj = json_decode(curl_get_contents($json_string),true);

        foreach ($obj['data'] as $key => $value) {
          echo @$value['id'];
          echo @$value['name'];
          echo @$value['start_time'];
          echo @$value['place'];
          echo @$value['cover']['source'];
        }

        function curl_get_contents($url)
        {
         $ch = curl_init($url);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
         $data = curl_exec($ch);
         curl_close($ch);
         return $data;
       }
     ?>
```